# How to get tw-in-js/twind plugins to work in Svelte

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css, twind, tailwind-in-js

I'm using tw-in-js/twind in Svelte.
when using the vanilla setup for Svelte App and after including Twind I cannot find any way to get plugins to work:

```
<script>
    import {tw, apply, setup} from 'twind/css';

    setup ({
        plugins: {
            h1style: apply`
                uppercase
                text-6xl
                font-thin
            `,
        },
    });

    const h1style2 = apply `uppercase text-6xl font-thin`;

    export let name;
</script>

<main>
    <h1 class={tw`h1style`}>Hello {name}!</h1>
    <p>Visit the <a href="https://svelte.dev/tutorial" class={tw`italic`}>Svelte tutorial</a> to learn how to build Svelte apps.</p>
</main>
```

In the code sample above h1style2 (the const declaration) works but the Plugin h1style does not.

I would appreciate knowing if anyone can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example in the Svelte Repl and it seems to work: https://svelte.dev/repl/e153da51e31a4b6c90cce63d9b6b3194?version=3.31.2

Here you find our example svelte project: https://github.com/tw-in-js/example-svelte

One thing to note is that `setup` should be outside of a component in the [app initializer](https://github.com/tw-in-js/example-svelte/blob/main/src/index.js) or within the `<script context="module">`. This ensures that `setup` is called only once per app.

Comment: Thanks @sastan for answering my question.  It seems I may have an environmental issue.  It does not work for me. I even downloaded the zip of the repl and that does not work either.  I'm running on Windows 10 and once the "setup" is put in I get a blank page in the browser - no errors anywhere - I'm now trying to figure out why. As I said above it works with the const appraoch but fails when using setup (which I've also tried in main.js as well

Comment: ok thanks again - the strange behavior came from potentially messed up config. My package.json had in dependencies twind:"^0.14.1".  This should not have been an issue as far as I can see. I ran npm install twind which brought it to 0.14.2 and changed the dependency to be "latest" (in accord with the example svelte-snowpack from  twind git site).  I moved the import and setup into the top of main.js and as a result of the npm install it's now working.